# How to read/write memory in a game c++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm creating a game trainer in c++ and have already wrote the code to connect with the game window and acquired the pointer for the in game value I wish to change, however when I try to change the in game value it doesn't work. im new to coding and c++.

Example of what I tried:

```
if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x01B2C89C, &value, newdatasize, NULL)) {

cout << "The value has been written sucessfully!!" << endl;

system("Pause");

  }else{

cout << "There was an error writing the value..." << endl;

system("Pause");

   }
```

I just keep getting different error messages.....

Comment: If your call to WriteProcessMemory() fails, you should get extended error information by calling GetLastError().
Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory

Answer (score 0):

- You need to run your program as administrator
- Ensure you get the correct process id
- Ensure OpenProcess returns a valid handle
- Use GetLastError() to discover the error code after WriteProcessMemory is called
- If 0x01B2C89C is not a static address (it doesn't look like it is), then you have to dynamically grab the correct address using moduleBaseAddress + relative offset

Use the Visual Studio Debugger, set a breakpoint on the first line of code.  Put GetLastError() in the watch window.  Step into every line of code and check GetLastError() to see when the first error occurs.  This is the best way to debug all WinAPI game hacking activities.